# Nginx cache for frequent and different requests

Tags: linux, nginx, performance, cache, high-load

I have a service.
This service has a GET handle(/api/v1/retrieve_blocks).
This handle's requests and responces are small, no more than 1024 characters.

**regular situation**:

- this handle is constantly under 500rps.
- Almost all requests are different by url's parameters.
  for example:
  host/api/v1/retrieve_blocks?entity_id=1111
  host/api/v1/retrieve_blocks?entity_id=2222
  host/api/v1/retrieve_blocks?entity_id=3333

**During incidents**:

- this handle could be under 4000rps.
- almost all aditional requests are repeated.

We decided to establish the nginx cache for stable operation during the incident.
But even at 500 rps, in a normal situation, the disk I/O in our service is overloaded, which leads to an increase in handle timings.

The **full** nginx configs is following:

```
nginx: [warn] could not build optimal variables_hash, you should increase either variables_hash_max_size: 1024 or variables_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring variables_hash_bucket_size
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes  4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;
daemon off;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  8192;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    
    
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    map_hash_bucket_size 128;

    #Enable gzip
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable    msie6;
    gzip_vary       on;
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    gzip_http_version   1.0;
    gzip_buffers        4 8k;
    gzip_comp_level     5;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json application/x-protobuf;

    #Increase fasctgi-buffers
    fastcgi_buffer_size 8192k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 16384k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 8192k;
        

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml xsl;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js yate;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json jsx;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/01-accesslog-tskv.conf:
tskv_log_format access_log_tskv $http_x_remote_ip $http_x_yarequestid $upstream_http_x_yarequestid $http_host $remote_addr $request_time $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status $upstream_status $scheme $bytes_sent $args $ssl_session_id $ssl_protocol $ssl_cipher $ssl_handshake_time $upstream_http_x_yataxi_api_operationid $request_body;
tskv_log_format access_log_tskv_no_body $http_x_remote_ip $http_x_yarequestid $upstream_http_x_yarequestid $http_host $remote_addr $request_time $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status $upstream_status $scheme $bytes_sent $args $ssl_session_id $ssl_protocol $ssl_cipher $ssl_handshake_time $upstream_http_x_yataxi_api_operationid;
tskv_log_format access_log_tskv_no_body_ja3 $http_x_remote_ip $http_x_yarequestid $upstream_http_x_yarequestid $http_host $remote_addr $request_time $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status $upstream_status $scheme $bytes_sent $args $ssl_session_id $ssl_protocol $ssl_cipher $ssl_handshake_time $upstream_http_x_yataxi_api_operationid $http_x_riotech_ja3;
tskv_log syslog:server=127.0.0.1 access_log_tskv_no_body;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/01-accesslog.conf:
log_format defaultformat '[$time_local] $http_host $remote_addr "$request" $status "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_cookie" $request_time $upstream_cache_status $bytes_sent "$upstream_response_time" $request_length $msec "$upstream_http_x_yareqfinish" "$sent_http_x_yauuid" "$upstream_http_x_yarequestid" "$upstream_http_x_yamisc" "$http_X_MSISDN_h121ZY615d623L631O2L3;$http_HW_3GPP_RAT_Type;$http_X_SGSN_IP;$http_X_MegaFon_IMSI" $http_x_remote_ip $http_x_real_ip "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$upstream_http_x_yataxi_api_operationid"';
access_log      syslog:server=127.0.0.1  defaultformat;
error_log       syslog:server=127.0.0.1;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/02-client-body-buffer-size.conf:
client_body_buffer_size 1m;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/riotech-geo-dorblu-agent.conf:
server {
    listen [::]:5033 ipv6only=off default_server;

    location /dorblu-unistat {
        root /var/lib/riotech/dorblu-agent;
        try_files /yasm_stats.json =404;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/riotech-taxi-service-name:
upstream taxi_service_name_upstream {
    server unix:/var/lib/riotech/taxi-service-name/server.socket;
    keepalive 600;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/riotech/taxi-service-name levels=1:2 keys_zone=qc_api_v1_blocks_zone:150m max_size=6g use_temp_path=off;

server {
    include listen;

    server_name service-name.taxi.dev.riotech.net;
    server_name service-name.taxi.tst.riotech.net;
    server_name service-name.taxi.riotech.net;

    client_max_body_size 3M;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://taxi_service_name_upstream/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    }

location /api/v1/blocks {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://taxi_service_name_upstream/api/v1/blocks;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

        sendfile on;

        proxy_cache qc_api_v1_blocks_zone;
        proxy_cache_key $scheme$request_method$proxy_host$request_uri;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1m;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/listen:
listen [::]:80;
listen [::]:8179;
listen [::]:8180;
include locations/404-any;
include locations/500-html;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/locations/404-any:
location @404 {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-riotech-NotFound-Project "autodetect";
    if ( $http_accept = application/json ) {
    set $custom_error_page "on";
    }
    if ( $server_port ~* '^(8079|8179)$' ) {
    set $custom_error_page "on";
    }
    if ( $host ~* "riotech.net" ) {
    set $custom_error_page "on";
    }
    if ( $custom_error_page !~ "on" ) {
    proxy_pass http://any.riotech.ru;
    }
}
error_page 404 @404;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/locations/500-html:
error_page 500 502 503 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root /usr/local/www/common/error-handlers;
}
```

Server's OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
It has about 20 GB of free RAM;
And only one disk which is ssd.

I will be very grateful for any advice and any information about the problem.
Concrete questions:

1. **Globally, what am I doing wrong?**
2. **Is nginx suitable for such purposes?**
3. **Can disabling nginx logs help?**
4. **Now I'm thinking about mounting the cache folder to RAM. Norm idea?**

Thank you for your attention)

Comment: Have you checked that the results are actually cached? Your upstream application needs to add proper headers so that nginx knows it can cache them

Comment: Yes, I see a heap of files located on the proxy_cache_path.
Each file contains the correct service response

And I checked caching many times by manual curls; It works as it was desired.

Comment: Please show your full configuration as shown by `nginx -T`, so we can see if there are things that can be improved.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen
Yes, sorry.
Here it is.
I Updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can be optimized is to change gzip compression level to 1. It doesn't change disk I/O, but it decreases CPU usage.

The `tskv` logging could be one reason for bad performance. I have no experience with that module, so I don't know how well-written it is.

For nginx normal logging, it is useful either to disable it, or make nginx write it to disk in batches:

```
access_log /path/to/access.log combined buffer=8k flush=1m;
```

This tells nginx to collect logs in memory for up to 1 megabyte, before it is written to disk.

Also, since your log target seems to be syslog, you might want to look into how syslog flushes its log files.